# UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage() Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to export a unity game to Android studio, there are multiple scenes in the game
so I used UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage to chose what scene I want to go to the start
But here is where the problem showed up

Here is the code for switching between the Main activity and unity

```
public void OpenTricky(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
    
    startActivity(intent);
    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObject", "LoadScene", "TrickyDodge/Scenes/Main menue");
}
public void OpenFly(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
    
    startActivity(intent);
    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObject", "LoadScene", "Flybird/Scenes/Mainmenu");
}
```

The game object name is ***GameObject*** and the Script name is ***Loading*** with the method ***LoadScene***

```
public class Loading : MonoBehaviour{
public void LoadScene(string sceneName)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(""+sceneName);
}
}
```

[here is the Scenes I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6klv.png)

Am I missing something??

Comment: Do you debug your code like the function LoadScene is called or not or it gives any error ?? by the way you can load scene using buildIndex so you don't have to give whole name just pass the index of the scene

Comment: From you java code I believe that first opened android activity and then you open UnityPlayerActivity. In this case after calling startActivity you have to wait sometime(because unity is yet initialized) and then called UnitySendMessage function

Comment: It really was a delay issue 
Thank you

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't start UnityPlayerActivity because it is the underlying activity that runs all the time.

Answer (score 0):

LoadScene should be static or else UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage cant call it